# Idiomatic way in Swift to typecast an UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> to an Array of non-void types?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

Many C/Obj-C APIs deal in pointers to void.  In swift, these types are typically represented as UnsafeMutablePointer or UnsafePointer (for const void*).  What is the typical way in Swift to reinterpret these values to a packed array of data, such as [Float] or [UInt8] ?

Comment: You may want to add a use case, the question is too generic. E.g. why do  you want to convert them to an array?

Comment: The specific scenaris is the use of MTLBuffer.contents(), which returns UnsafePointer<Void>, since the data is just a bag of bits as far as the API is concerned.  The calling code knows the correct interpretation, but needs to reinterpret the type accordingly in order to access it naturally.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to cast it to `UInt8` pointer:

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(MTLBuffer.contents())
```

And you can access it using subscript operators:

```
for index in 0 ..< bufferSize {
    let foo = buffer[index]      // foo is `UInt8` type
    ...
    buffer[index] = bar
}
```